# How can I add additional information with each multipart image file in okhttp3

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-volley, multipartform-data, okhttp

Here, I am sending my image files to the server as multipart data dynamically:

```
MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("title", json);  

for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {
     File imageFile = imageList.get(i).getImageFile();
     if (imageFile.exists()) {
         builder.addFormDataPart("images[" + i + "]", imageList.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image"), imageFile));
     }
}

MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
```

Now, I want to add an additional information `created_at` as `String` to each of the images to the server. How can I achieve this? Is it possible in **Retrofit/Volley**? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**You can achive to your goal with code below**

**Your retrofit service**

```
 @Multipart
 @POST(value = "example/endpoint")
 Call<ResponseBody> uploadImages(
        @Part(value = "created_at") RequestBody createdAt,
        @Part(value = "image") MultipartBody.Part image
 );
```

**How to convert String to RequestBody**

```
RequestBody.create(String.valueOf(createdAt), MediaType.parse("text/plain"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this solution will work only for single image. I want to do the same thing for list of images without calling the API multiple times.

Comment: You are welcome, maybe you may try `@Part(value = "images") List<MultipartBody.Part> `images instead of `@Part(value = "image") MultipartBody.Part image`

Comment: But how can I add list of `created_at` for corresponding `List<MultipartBody.Part>`. I want to create a list of custom object where CustomObject will contain two fields `MultipartBody.Part` & `created_at`. Will it be possible?